# Gradient of $f(W)=\sum_{j \neq {t}} \left[ \max\left(0, [ W x ]_j - \left[ W x \right]_{t} + \delta \right) \right] + \lambda \left\| W \right\|_F^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

How to find the gradient of the following function 
\begin{align}
f(W) := \sum_{j \neq {t}} \left[ \max\left(0, [ W x ]_j - \left[ W x \right]_{t} + \delta \right) \right] + \lambda \left\| W \right\|_F^2 \ ,
\end{align}
w.r.t. $W \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ matrix, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\delta, \lambda$ are known variables. The $j$th element of a vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is denoted as $[y]_j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max function isn't differentiable, but you could replace it with a [smooth-max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_maximum) approximation. Or you could try this...

Define the variables
$$\eqalign{
 y &= Wx, \quad dy = dW\,x \cr
 k &= t, \quad z = (1e_k^T)y = Ky \cr
 b &= (y-z + 1\delta) = (I-K)y + 1\delta \cr
 s &= {\rm sign}(b), \quad p = \tfrac{1}{2}(1+s) \cr
 a &= p\odot b = \max(0,b)\cr
}$$
where max() and sign() are applied elementwise and the latter is defined as
$${\rm sign}(\beta)=\begin{cases}
+1  &  \beta \ge 0 \\
-1  &  \beta \lt 0
\end{cases}$$

Write the function in terms of these variables and find its gradient
$$\eqalign{
 f &= 1:a + \lambda W:W - \delta \cr
  &= p:b + \lambda W:W - \delta \cr
\cr
df &= p:db + 2\lambda W:dW \cr
   &= p:(I-K)dy + 2\lambda W:dW \cr
   &= p:(I-K)dW\,x + 2\lambda W:dW \cr
   &= \Big((I-K)^Tpx^T + 2\lambda W\Big):dW \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}
 &= \Big(I-e_k1^T\Big)px^T + 2\lambda W \cr
}$$
**NB:**  The above derivation uses the symbol {$\odot$} for the elementwise/Hadamard product, {$e_k$} for the standard basis vectors, {$1$} for the all-ones vector, and {:} for the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)
}$$
Instead of a smooth-max function, you could re-work the above approach with a smooth-sign function, e.g. $\tanh(\mu b)$ with a sufficiently large $\mu$-parameter.
$$\lim_{\mu\to\infty}\tanh(\mu b) = {\rm sign}(b)$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Your result is great (+1), but I must admit that I have not been able to digest yet. On the other hand, how is your result related to the gradient they have here (without any derivations) http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-1/#analytic? Is your result similar?

Comment: The paper is using an _indicator function_ which appears to be their name for an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), anyway it's the quantity represented by the $p$-vector in my post.

Comment: Another difference is that the paper has calculated $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial w_j}$ so pre/post-multiplying my _matrix_ gradient by $(e_j, e_i)$ where $(i,j\ne k)$ yields $p_jx_i$ which is the same as their _scalar_ result. And of course omitting the regularization term. Oh, _and_ they're using the opposite layout convention from me.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.